# How one executes a periodic job in gtk application?

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I need to make an application with GUI built on gtk, that checks socekets for incoming messages and displays statistics as they are gathered without any imput from user.
How can this be organised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd know how to do it using PyGtk and PyGObject but I never did something like it in C. However, I have a suggestion to you: try the [`g_io_add_watch` function](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch) from GLib (which is base for GObject as well). It worked well in Python for me (and were much more practical to use BTW) and the Python version is just a wrapper for the original C function. Since GTK+ is based in GObject and GObject uses GLib extensively, you already have this function available in your development environment and it should work well with GTK+.

Comment: if possible, i'd like to use a timed call, like every 0.2 seconds instead of listening to each channel as it activates (there are 8 in my task). Are tehre ways to do that?

Comment: Sure you can! Actually, it would be _easier_ to do using the [`g_timeout_add` function](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add). However, I _suspect_ it would be at least a bit less efficient.