# C GTK+ periodic event to update the UI

Tags: c, events, gtk

How can I update a GTK+ interface on a periodic event. For example, let's say I wanted to update a text field containing the time every 200 milliseconds. How is this typically done?

---

**Update:**

Another question ([How one executes a periodic job in gtk application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805698/how-one-executes-a-periodic-job-in-gtk-application)) mentiones g_timeout_add. Is this the best way to go about doing this? It is said in that thread that it may not be efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/gtkevents/) has an example.  (Search for the section titled "A timer example".)

The short answer is "use [`g_timeout_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add)".

Comment: Added my update before I saw your answer. It sounds like this may be the route to take..