# How to create an interrupt or background task in C

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, gtk3

I am trying to figure out how to make a background process in C, I haven't found anything online. I think the reason I haven't found much is that I may not be asking the right question.

I am working on a school project using ARM assembly and C with Raspberry Pi using the Raspbian Operating System and the GCC compiler.

For my project, I decided to do a simple alarm system. The idea is simple, I have 3 PIR sensors that detect motion, and set off a buzzer when motion is detected.

Instead of using hardware for the keypad, I chose to do a GUI where you can arm/disarm the system as well as change the password and turn on/off certain sensors. For example, if you wanted to turn off motion sensors 1 and 2, there will be buttons on the GUI to do that.

The problem I am having is that the GUI Library I'm using, (GTK3 and Glade) is event-driven, so unless a button is pressed it won't do anything. This would be fine if I only wanted to set the buzzer to on when motion is detected because I could make my own loop to watch for motion, but I really want to play some type of pattern repeatedly (example: 3 short beeps continuously until the alarm is disarmed). At the same time, I still want to have access to the GUI buttons so I can turn off the alarm. This makes me think I need an interrupt or a background process.

I'm sure there are many ways to solve this problem, but I really wanted to create sort of a background routine that could run parallel to the main task once the user's arms' the system. I have asked my professor about how to multi-thread in ARM, but he said that we do not cover this in the class. I have read that the C standard library doesn't support multi-threading, but I am sure there is a way that this can be done. If someone could just point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Here is the GUI code I have written, along with another module I have finished to get a working prototype before I start wiring the sensors. None of this contains any assembly code because I haven't got to that yet, I wanted to get it working at a higher level and then break certain parts down to assembly. If you need all of the files I will gladly provide them, but I think this should be enough for you all to understand what I'm trying to do.

The GUI code:

```
/*****************************************************
 * Title:       User Interface
 * Author:      
 * Date:        2/15/20
 * Class:       CISP 2410
 *
 * Description:
 *  ! This header file contains all of the function
 *  ! Declarations and definitions for the GUI
 *  ! Everything involving the GUI will be in
 *    --> this header
 *
 *****************************************************/



#include <gtk/gtk.h>        // For gtk stuff
#include <stdlib.h>         // Standard Library
#include "GUI_Ctrl.h"       // Prototypes
#include "Alarm.h"          // Alarm Functions



/* Private Functions */

static void UpdateLcdDisplay(char keyPadValue);
static void ClearLcdDisplay(void);
static void UpdateDisplay(void);
/***********************************/



// Global Variables
GtkWidget *g_Lbl_Lcd;
GtkWidget *g_Lbl_SysStat;
GtkWidget *g_Lbl_LogStat;


char inputBuffer[6] = {0x0};
int charCounter = 0;
const int INPUT_LIMIT = 6;




/*****************************************************
 * ! Initializes all of the GUI elements
 * ! Adds CSS attributes to GUI elements
 * ! Also handles the formatting of text 
 *****************************************************/
void GUI_INIT(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder  *builder; 
    GtkWidget   *window;
    GtkWidget *g_Lbl_Lbl1;
    GtkWidget *g_Lbl_Lbl2;

    // Get pointer to css file
    GtkCssProvider *cssProvider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(cssProvider,"UI/style.css",NULL);

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // get pointer to xml dat file
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("UI/HelloWorld.glade");

    // Get pointer to main window
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    // Get pointer to labels
    g_Lbl_Lcd = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Lbl_Lcd"));
    g_Lbl_SysStat = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Lbl_SysStat"));
    g_Lbl_LogStat = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Lbl_LogStat"));
    g_Lbl_Lbl1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Lbl1"));
    g_Lbl_Lbl2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "Lbl2"));

    // Align Text Right
    gtk_label_set_xalign (GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_Lcd), 1);
    // Align Text Left
    gtk_label_set_xalign (GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_SysStat), 0);
    gtk_label_set_xalign (GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_LogStat), 0);
    gtk_label_set_xalign (GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_Lbl1), 0);
    gtk_label_set_xalign (GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_Lbl2), 0);

    // Add CSS
    gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(gdk_screen_get_default(), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider), GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);


    // Finish setup and start GUI
    g_object_unref(builder);
    gtk_widget_show(window);    
    UpdateDisplay();           
    gtk_main();
    return;
}



// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}


/*------------------END SECTION------------------*/




static void UpdateDisplay(void)
{
    ClearLcdDisplay();
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_SysStat), GetSysStat());
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_LogStat), GetLogStat());
    return;
}

static void UpdateLcdDisplay(char keyPadValue)
{
    if (charCounter >= INPUT_LIMIT)
        ClearLcdDisplay();
    else
    {
        inputBuffer[charCounter] = keyPadValue;
        charCounter++;
    }
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_Lcd), inputBuffer);
    return;
}

static void ClearLcdDisplay(void)
{
    memset(inputBuffer, 0, 6);
    charCounter = 0;
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_Lbl_Lcd), inputBuffer);
    return;
}




/*------------------ EVENT HANDLERS ------------------*/

void on_btn0_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('0');}
void on_btn1_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('1');}
void on_btn2_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('2');}
void on_btn3_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('3');}
void on_btn4_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('4');}
void on_btn5_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('5');}
void on_btn6_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('6');}
void on_btn7_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('7');}
void on_btn8_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('8');}
void on_btn9_clicked(void)      {UpdateLcdDisplay('9');}
void on_btnClear_clicked(void)  {ClearLcdDisplay();}
void on_btnEnter_clicked(void)   {UpdateDisplay();}

void on_btnLogin_clicked(void)
{
    LoginLogout(inputBuffer);
    UpdateDisplay(); 
    return;
}

void on_btnArm_clicked(void)
{
    ArmDisarm();
    UpdateDisplay(); 
    return;
}
```

Here is the code for the alarm. Note, this is just a prototype, I will be using the wiringPi library once I get this interrupt thing figured out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Alarm.h"


// Private Function Prototypes
static int PasswordIsCorrect(char* pswAttempt);

// Global Variables
static int armed = 0;
static int loggedIn = 0;





static int PasswordIsCorrect(char* pswAttempt)
{
    const char PASSWORD[] = "123";

    if (!strcmp(pswAttempt, PASSWORD))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}



/*
 * Returns a string,
 * Used to update label
 */
char* GetSysStat(void)
{
    if(armed)
        return "Armed";
    else
        return "Disarmed";
}


/*
 * Returns a string,
 * Used to update label
 */
char* GetLogStat(void)
{
    if(loggedIn)
        return "Logged In";
    else
        return "Logged Out";
}



void ArmDisarm(void)
{
    if (loggedIn && armed)
        armed = 0;
    else if(loggedIn && !armed)
        armed = 1;
    return;
}



void LoginLogout(char* pswAttempt)
{
    if(PasswordIsCorrect(pswAttempt))
        loggedIn = 1;
    else
        loggedIn = 0;
    return;
}
```

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: I'm thinking POSIX threads... https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: It is your operating system who has to manage multi-threading via its scheduler. that why it is not implemented as part of the C standard library since your program could be a bare metal software, or could use any available operating system (Linux, FreeRTOS, etc...). Since you are using Linux, you should go for POSIX Threads (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads).

Comment: You could use this: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal So that your ISR unblocks your thread by using the pthread_cond_signal() function

Comment: Basically you want to run some code every few milliseconds? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240691/c-gtk-periodic-event-to-update-the-ui

Comment: Yes, the POSIX threads are what I was looking for. Thank you all!

Comment: @user253751 I looked at your suggestion also, I might actually go with that since I'm already using GTK, instead of adding a thread. Thanks.

Comment: You really need to learn how gtk works. And yes Timers is what you need, not threads. Start learning gtk without glade.